# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC isn't installing ( Error: Update 2 RC does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msdn

This is the error image and the next image shows i have VS2013 installed with Update 1

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC error:
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tLiGHIoOHHg/U1dWwhMG7qI/AAAAAAAAAek/CA_VCulggd0/s1600/Error.png

Proof of Visual Studio 2013 Update 1:
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-gs3zPKsS8K8/U1dWxHHmg7I/AAAAAAAAAes/8HP-7FTaBnw/s1600/Visual+Studio+Update+1.png

Comment: The log can be found here: 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8A078F1C32A76AF1!4181&authkey=!AN1UsVFH_-IbU-U&ithint=file%2c.txt

Comment: Did you try the VS repair function?

Comment: There is no Repair option when you install this update.

Comment: Did you click the link that describes common problems? What did you find there?

Comment: It redirects me here, which is of no use:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=349214&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer never helped me.
The problem was my Operating System wasn't detecting my Visual Studio 2013, even though i tried to reinstall it, instead it was already installed but was never detected by computer.

I used cmd to uninstall VS2013 by command eg. "uninstall c:/...devenv.exe /Force" and then again installed VS2013 and applied the update

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when installing **Update 2** for my **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web**.

The reason in my case was because before the installation I was doing some housekeeping and deleted content of this folder c:\Users\All Users\Package Cache\

When I restored it back, there was no error message and the installation was successful.

That means, you might have missing bundles and your installer is not happy with that. In my case I had a backup but if I haven't had I would need to reinstall my **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web** so all is good and in place and then installation of the update should be hassle free.

More less the same as mentioned in the article from the link above. Thanks Keval.